# XMLHttpRequest GET call returning 500 error, but curl works

Tags: javascript, curl, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-500

I am trying to retrieve data from an API, but am getting a status 500 error.

I am able to get the data perfectly fine when running this in my terminal:

```
curl -u myApiKey: https://api.racehero.io/v1/events/38247
```

but when I try and retrieve it in JavaScript with the given sample code from the [API docs](https://racehero.docs.apiary.io/#/reference/0/resource-2/get-details-about-a-single-event/200?mc=reference%2F0%2Fresource-2%2Fget-details-about-a-single-event%2F200) I get the status 500 error.
Here is my JavaScript code below, with the only modification to the sample code provided being the added ('Authorization', 'Basic myApiKey') to the request header.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require('xhr2');
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('GET', 'https://api.racehero.io/v1/events/38247');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic myApiKey:');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

request.send();
```

Any help is appreciated!

I tried doing it in python as well as different calls, but keep running into the same issue.

Comment: the XMLHttpRequest equivalent of that curl command would be `request.open('GET', 'https://api.racehero.io/v1/events/38247', true, myApiKey, "");`

Comment: alternatively, `request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic '+btoa('myApiKey:'));`